# How to get a list of all parents in directory that their children are files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk, pathlib

I have a tree of directories that in the end of the each directory will always be 2 files, one as suffix ".txt" and one will always be ".jpg", for example:
"rootFolder/a/a.txt", "rootFolder/a/b.jpg"
"rootFolder/b/c/a.txt", "rootFolder/b/c/b.jpg"
and I want that the output will be:
["rootFolder/a", "rootFolder/b/c"]

```
import pathlib
root = pathlib.Path("/rootFolder")
paths = list(root.rglob("*.txt")) + list(root.rglob("*.jpg"))
```

this code give me the pathes of the files but i want their parents and i'm pretty sure that i there is one line code that do it but i didn't figure it out.

Comment: What did you use to try and get the parent of a file from that file's path?

Comment: I want to do it with one simple line that catch all and i get all the files and not their parents

Comment: That's what you *want*; what did you *try*?

Comment: I describe what i did

Comment: You would do something like `{p.parent for p in paths}`

Answer (score 1):

So, just use `dirname` to remove the filename part of the path, and convert it to a set to remove duplicates:

```
paths = set([os.path.dirname(p) for p in paths])
```

Comment: thank you i used set([p.parent.absolute() for p in paths]) and it workes